# Why does this topology cause artifact and how to fix it?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, topology

I have this mesh:

[image]

When subdivided it causes an artifact here:

[image]

I'm not sure what's going on. It's not a pole, and all surrounding faces are quads. What causes this artifact? And how can I fix it?

Comment: You could try selecting that vertex and the surrounding ones in edit mode and then Vertex > Smooth Vertices to see if it helps.

Comment: maybe there's an inner edge (or inner face, overlapping vertices...). If you don't see anything, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: My guess is a stray, duplicate, or unattached vertex. Try selecting the whole mesh, then press M (merge), and select "by distance". If that doesn't work, (with the mesh still selected), try picking _mesh > normals > recalculate outside_ from the menu at the top of the 3D viewport.

Comment: Thank you all! There was a duplicate vertex. After I remove it, the subdiv works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others suggested, the culprit is a inner vertex. For the reference, one can use `Select -> Selecty All by Trait -> Non Manifold` to find this kind of problem.

[image]